# C++ Opengl fstream ctype.h error

Tags: c++, opengl, fstream

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to include fstream library. Here is my code:

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void drawPolyLine() {
    fstream inStream;
    inStream.open("dino.dat", ios::in);
    if (inStream.fail()) return;
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLint numPolys,  numLines, x, y;
    inStream >> numPolys;
    for (int j = 0; j < numPolys; j++)
    {
        inStream >> numLines;
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (int i=0; i< numLines;  i++)
        {
            inStream >> x >> y;
            glVertex2i(x, y); 
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    inStream.close();
}

void DrawTilling2(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            if((i + j) % 2 == 0) gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 440);
            else gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 440, 0);

            glViewport(i * 64, j * 44, 64, 44);
            drawPolyLine();
        }

    glFlush();
}

void DrawTilling(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            glViewport(i * 64, j * 44, 64, 44);
            drawPolyLine();
        }
    glFlush();
}

void Init() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc,  argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Tilling  dinosaurus");
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawTilling2);
    Init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried to compile it, it shows error related to ctype.h (which I didn't include at all in my code). Here's the compile log:

```
Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.8.1 32-bit Profiling
Building Makefile "U:\Campus\5th Semester\Computer Graphics\T4 GRAFKOM\dino\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
mingw32-make.exe -f "U:\Campus\5th Semester\Computer Graphics\T4 GRAFKOM\dino\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -D__DEBUG__ -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -m32 -pg -g3

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cctype:42:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\localefwd.h:42,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:41,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from main.cpp:3:
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:4:13: error: redefinition of 'const int A'
 const int   A = 500;  /* length of a side of the monitor window */
             ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:16:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from main.cpp:2:

c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:4:13: error: 'const int A' previously defined here
 const int   A = 500;  /* length of a side of the monitor window */
             ^
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cctype:42:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\localefwd.h:42,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:41,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from main.cpp:3:
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:5:13: error: redefinition of 'const float B'
 const float B = 500;  /* length of a side of the clipping rectangle */

             ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:16:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from main.cpp:2:

c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:5:13: error: 'const float B' previously defined here

 const float B = 500;  /* length of a side of the clipping rectangle */
             ^
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cctype:42:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\localefwd.h:42,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:41,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from main.cpp:3:
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:6:13: error: redefinition of 'const float C'
 const float C = 200;  /* length of a side of the square the program draws */
             ^
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:16:0,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from main.cpp:2:
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ctype.h:6:13: error: 'const float C' previously defined here
 const float C = 200;  /* length of a side of the square the program draws */
             ^


U:\Campus\5th Semester\Computer Graphics\T4 GRAFKOM\dino\Makefile.win:29: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

(some parts of the log are omitted).

I'm using Dev-Cpp 5.4.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Double check, that you didn't damage your `ctype.h` header. These errors look like if by accident some variable definitions that are intended to be in main somehow ended up there.

Comment: The code seems to worked fine in my friends computer, though. It looks like the `#include <fstream>` that is causing problems, because when I delete it the error won't show up (but the code didn't work either). Or maybe it's just my compiler, but I've reinstalled it already. I just want to know whether there is a workaround for this issue.